# Using RefreshIndicator with StreamBuilder and Future

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a list of items that I can refresh by using the `RefreshIndicator` I have created a `Stream` using a `Future` and added a `StreamBuilder` to the UI. I have also attached the Future call to the RefreshIndicator. For some reason the UI does not update when I pull to refresh. I assume it has something to do with how I have the Stream and Future set up. Can someone take a look and let me know if I am doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Here is the UI

```
class EntityList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context);
    var opsProvider = Provider.of<OperationsProvider>(context);

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: opsProvider.getEntitiesStream(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData ? RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () => opsProvider.getEntities(),
          child: Container(
            height: double.maxFinite,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data['content'].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                ......
              }
            )
          ),
        ) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the Provider class:

```
class OperationsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future getEntities() async {
    return await ApiService.get(Config.kpis + 'dashboard?page=0&size=15');
  }

  Stream getEntitiesStream() async* {
    yield await this.getEntities();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @AjilO.unfortunately not :/